# JQuery Mobile Back Button does not work with Cordova 1.9.0 and Android 2.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've spent the last few hours pulling my hair out on what should be a simple problem.

I'm trying to make use of the backButton feature in JQuery mobile to build a site which has navigation icons. (It is my understanding that JQM simply calls window.history.back)

The site works perfectly as expected in a desktop browser, and mobile safari. The site does not work in Android WebView. (It's worth noting that the actual hardware 'clear' button works and takes the user back one page, but the JQM icon just highlights and goes nowhere.)

At some point I said screw it, and just called window.history.back myself, but this does nothing on the phone.

Here's the software:

- JQuery Mobile 1.1.0
- Cordova/PhoneGap 1.9.0
- Android 2.2

I've looked at a number of questions already asked, but none of them provided solutions that appear to be valid in the 1.1.0/1.9.0 combination on Android. I've also tried Cordova 1.8 and 1.7, same problem.

Here is a simple page header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Here is a call using the JQM built-in feature:

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

Here is a call using my own construct:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#backButton").click(handleBackButton);
});

function handleBackButton() {
    window.history.back(); //Cordova does something funky with this on Android
}

...

<a id="backButton" href="index.html" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

**Update**

See this Gist for some examples of the forward navigation model. Notice the `data-ajax="false"` going to page 4.

**Update 2**
Updated gist to include a call to `navigator.app.backHistory()` as "Cordova Back". This works to go back and forth between physical pages, but fails to adhere to the JQM page DOM model. Any ideas on how to unify both?
https://gist.github.com/3039722

I would prefer not to modify the core Cordova.js code, but rather add some listener in the app that takes care of this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Works fine with cordova 1.9 and Android 2.2. Using `back` in three different way:

Override backbutton:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, true);
}

function handleBackButton() {
    console.log("back clicked");
    window.history.back();
}
```

With `data-rel=back`

```
<a data-rel="back" data-role="button">Rel Back</a>
```

With click handler

```
<a id="forceBack" data-role="button">Force Back</a>

...

$("#forceBack").click(function(){
    history.back();
});
```

For full source - https://gist.github.com/3037838

Comment: Yes. Your code works, however it's not set up in the same navigation model as my actual app. I've clarified above the forward navigation model.  Adding a 3rd and 4th page (separate file) breaks the 'Force Back' feature. Adding `data-ajax="false"` to the link to page 4 breaks the 'Rel Back' feature. https://gist.github.com/3039722

Comment: actually you have also kept the button id same for `page2` and `page3` which wont work as element id should be unique in one html file or DOM tree.

Comment: `data-rel=back` will not work when you move to next page with page refresh, `data-ajax=false` just does that only.

Comment: Hmm. I thought uniqueness at the 'page' div was enough. I have a combination of `data-ajax=false` and true, so I'm guessing the `data-rel=back` isn't going to work for me. Why dosn't the force work? Even with the same IDs on index.html#page3 and page4, shouldn't the window.history.back() force the page back one?