# jquery with external link website

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a webapp mobile application. I am using jQuery mobile 1.9 +  phonegap 2.4.

When I generate a page of HTML with listview, and the page is local on the web server or local in mobile, I can click in a listview item and I see back button, because I have defined `data-add-back-btn="true"` on all pages

But when I use an external link or if the local page is moved to a web server, when I click in item listview, I cannot see the back button and I can not go back.

Is this a bug in jQuery? How I can resolve this?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Because when you use `data-rel=external` for anchor, Ajax is disabled and page is loaded normally without the help of Ajax. Thus, browsing history built by Ajax is wiped.

Comment: I don't use data-rel=external.

Comment: Are you using multi-page template or multi-files?

Comment: multi-files, all files add format jquery page with data-role="page" id="...", data-role="header", etc

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303489/jquery-mobile-back-button-does-not-work-with-cordova-1-9-0-and-android-2-2

Comment: Thanks Omar, i am tried add data-rel="back" in orgin page, but if you but data-rel="back" when you click in link, your page go back history page. I want that this do it the target page. But if i add this link with button in target page, the button is show anytime , and i don't want this, i only what show , when i load this target page since app mobile, and not when someboby access surfing from web

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you mean. What do you exactly want?

Comment: I want to do a listview with link a external web. I said, If I use a web local in phone or directory the link is right, but if i copy this web to a web server. The button back don't show it

Comment: Put another way, i want do a listview with link to other domain web

Comment: i think the problem is cross-domain

Comment: please, somebody have some idea?

Comment: Can add some code? like how you set `data-add-back-btn` to all pages, your listview links, etc...

Comment: Hi Omar The example code is this

I create one listview with link to local page and all is right
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="page1.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Audi</a></li>
</ul>

but if the link are the same page in external domain, don't show back button
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="www.domain.com/page1.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.domain.com/page2.html">Audi</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Pls update your question with that code.

Comment: for example one page target called page1.html is:<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <TITLE></TITLE>
 
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="es-ES" DIR="LTR">
<div data-role="page" id="menus" data-add-back-btn="true" >
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> <h1>prueba</h1> </div> </div> </body></html>

Comment: if this page is in local domain , all right <ul data-role="listview"> <li><a href="page1.html">Acura</a></li></ul>, but if this page is in other domain <ul data-role="listview"> <li><a href="www.domain.com/page1.html">Acura</a></li></ul> the button back don't show

Comment: I think the problem is that when you load in local reference you call your web with protocol file:// but when you call a cross-domain must use http://

Comment: Maybe, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but if you delete http in link jquery do error

Comment: Why would you want to use domain, while all files/links are within one domain?

Comment: I access a external site, I need load the information of this webs. This information change all days

Comment: I will try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847893/cross-domain-issue-with-jquery , surfing in stackoverflow i find more issues with the same problem with cross-domain

Comment: I Omar thanks for your recomendation but i continue with the same problem. Is the last error i have for finish webapp. My code of this page is this http://pastebin.com/9nmAGagW

Comment: try this code `$(document).on('click', '#forceBack', function () { $.mobile.changePage($.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')); });` instead of `history.back()`.

Comment: The same, i have put the this code here: http://pastebin.com/TL13nr0U

Comment: are you getting any error? is this the homepage? first page renders?

Comment: No,i haven't got errors, when i click listview, the hmtl change the new page and show it, Don't is posible and compatible with html5 standard show the new page in frame under? because i think in this standard for mobile devices are't available this option

Comment: hombre! add `data-add-back-btn="true"` to `<div data-role="page">` not content div.

Comment: This is right, but don't back , i have put  <div data-role="content" data-add-back-btn="true"> but when i change other web it forget button back, i am testing in firefox/Internet explorer in PC.

Comment: is posible open external page in dialog or frame ??

Comment: 3 months after trying, you can really make a lisview pages containing external and returning to lisview in a webapp?

Comment: Lo siento, I'm still unable to understand the problem. What are you trying to achieve? What are you getting?

Comment: Si, un poco. No entiendo cual es el problema.

Comment: Te lo muestro en imágenes: Esto es la pantalla con el listview http://grab.by/rjFG al hacer click carga el contenido que es sacado de una web externa (todas son del mismo dominio externo) muestra esta pantalla http://grab.by/rjFQ, a partir de aquí no puedo volver atras(En iOS) y he perdido mi tabbar

Comment: Mándame un mensaje por el email, omarmt arroba gmail com

Comment: is posible download external web in local ?, so i can use page in local domain.

Comment: The solutions is installed plugin inAppBrowser and use window.open